# How to transfer the contents of iPad gen 2 (in 2023)?

Tags: ipad

How do I transfer the contents of an iPad Gen 2 to another iPad Gen 2? My old iPad is cracked, so I bought another iPad Gen 2 on eBay. I'd like to copy the cracked one's contents to the new one.

I have tried using iTunes for this (making a backup of the old one and installing it on the new one) - BUT - iTunes insists on downloading apps from the app store and many aren't there any more - so it's not working.

Any workarounds for this? I really want my old apps on the new ipad.

Comment: What OS are you running on your computer?

Comment: Win 7 Pro (yeah, I know I shouldn't be still on it...). 
Though I do think the problem is a change in iTunes, that downloads apps from the store and not the backup. I tried to get around this by downloading an old version of iTunes but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: It probably helps in this case. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303655/rearrange-apps-in-itunes-for-windows  get that older Windows [32 or 64 as appropriate] version of iTunes. It will backup the ipa files of each app too - then restore them to the new iPad.

Comment: @Tetsujin, didn't work. Newer versions of don't download apps from the computer but from the app store. 
I got a popup - "This computer is no longer authorized for apps that are installed on the iPad. Would you like to authorize this computer for items purchased from the iTunes Store?"

Comment: I know newer versions don't install [or backup] the apps, that's why I said to get that specific older version. if it asks you to authorise the computer, then why don't you? You can have 5 computers authorised at any one time & recycle them if you run out of slots.